# Blur filter в CSS

Tags: html, css

как задать `blur filter` на чистом `css` div'у с `background: url()` только в пределах другого `div`?

Пример на фото, через `filter: blur(10px)` получаются нечёткие границы размытия

[image: PSD пример]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оберните `div` со свойством `blur` в `div` со свойством `overflow:hidden` :

```css
.parent{
  background-image:url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg");
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  height:200px;
  padding:50px 0;
}
.inner{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.blur{
  background-image:url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg");
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  height:100px;
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner"><div class="blur"></div></div>
</div>
```